# Unable to retrieve data from Firebase using Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
[userRef child:@"notifications"] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot) block is not executing,

[[FIRAuth auth] signInWithCustomToken:token completion:^(FIRUser *user, NSError *error) {
     if(!error) {
        FIRDatabaseReference* databaseRef = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];
        NSString* userid = user.uid;

        FIRDatabaseReference* userRef = [databaseRef child:userid];
        [[userRef child:@"notifications"] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.value != [NSNull null]) {
                self.snapshot = snapshot;
                NSError* error;
                NSArray* notificationsData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:(NSArray*)self.snapshot.value];
                NSArray* notifications = [Notification arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries:notificationsData error:&error];
            }
        } withCancelBlock:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"error");
        }];
    }
 }];
```

This is my code to access this data of user from Firebase.

[image]

Comment: Inside notification what is that 'childByAutoId' ?

Comment: Keep in mind hierarchy to get notification object ,say [[[users objectAtIndex:o] objectForKey:@"notifications"]  objectAtIndex:0].

Comment: no its not 'childByAutoId'.. its just a notification id for notification object assigned by server

Comment: @AvijitNagare.. i didnt get you in terms of firebase reference

Comment: Have you tried printing the snapshot data in the console?

Comment: Did you resolve this problem? I have the same problem

Comment: @adithya ya I resolved it using callback     [self.notificationsRef observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
}withCancelBlock:^(NSError *error)  {
}];